# Grails: how to display images in <g:each> tag?

Tags: image, grails, groovy, each

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grails: displaying created image in gsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502278/grails-displaying-created-image-in-gsp)

I'm trying to display images from database in `<g:each>` tag.

my **domain-class:**

```
class Artists {
    byte[] image

    String artistName
    String bio

    static constraints = {
        image(nullable:true , maxSize:200000)
        artistName(nullable:true)
        bio(nullable:true, maxSize:2000)
    }

}
```

and **artists.gsp :**

```
<g:each in="${dog.Artists.list()}">
    <g:img src="${it.image }" width="120" height="160"/>  //doesn't work, what should I do here???
    <p>Name: ${it.artistName}</p>                         //works  
    <p>Biography: ${it.bio}</p>                           //works
</g:each>
```

help please !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can render the image inline the way you're attempting using the rendering plugin, and the following gsp tag (This is for a png Check [Inline Images](http://gpc.github.com/grails-rendering/docs/manual/index.html) in the docs for other content types):

```
<rendering:inlinePng bytes="${it.image}"/>
```