# How to bind Byte array saved in SQL DB to Image tag in GSP in a DataGrid?

Tags: grails, groovy, datagrid, gsp

I have domain property of Type Byte[].

```
byte[] photos
byte[] video
```

On GSP Page I am able to upload my files in SQL DB successfully. 
When I view the page to see list of elements in a row, my action of controller does the job , how do I set the image source to this Byte array retrieved from DB.

I hope my question is clear.

After following the instructions, here is what I did..

```
def displayGraph() {
    //def img = params.id // byte array
    def classified = Classified.findById(params.id)
    byte[] imageInByte=classified.photos.toByteArray();

    response.setHeader('Content-length', imageInByte.length)
    response.contentType = 'image/png' // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << imageInByte
    response.outputStream.flush()

    }
```

In GSP Page,  here is the code.

```
<td><img src="${createLink(controller: 'Classified', action: 'displayGraph', params: ['id': classifiedInstance.id])}"/></td>
```

I am getting below error now:

```
2014-05-03 19:17:05,723 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -
MissingMethodException occurred when processing request:   
[GET]/XXXClassified/classified/displayGraph/1
No signature of method: [B.toByteArray() is applicable for argument types: () values:  
[]. Stacktrace follows: Message: No signature of method: [B.toByteArray() is applicable  
for argument types: () values: []
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502278/grails-displaying-created-image-in-gsp

Comment: It should help because it addresses your problem. If not, describe in more detail what steps did you take and what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. Finally I was able to solve this puzzle.
Here is the code that fixed by problem:

```
class ImageProcessingController {

def DisplayImage() {
    def classified = Classified.findById(params.id)
    byte[] imageInByte=classified.photos
    response.contentType = 'image/png' // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << imageInByte
    response.outputStream.flush()
    }
}
```

GSP code snippet:

```
<td><img height=100, width=100 src="${createLink(controller: 'ImageProcessing', action: 'DisplayImage', params: ['id': classifiedInstance.id])}"/></td>
```

=======================================================================
What I learnt:
1. response.setHeader was throwing exception. Not sure why

```
response.setHeader('Content-length', imageInByte.length)
```

2. No need to convert byte array to Byte array using "toByteArray()"